# Deleting multiple rows using checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Game Library</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
<div id="search">
    <img id="del" src="img/delete.jpg" alt="Error">
        <a class="A" href="index.php"><img class="AR" src="img/src.jpg" title="Search library"></a>
            <a class="A" href="insert.php"><img class="AR" src="img/add.png" title="Add game"></a>
    <div id="results">
    <?php  
        require("inc/connection.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM Library";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            ?><div id="results">
            <form action="inc/delete.php" method="GET">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"  value="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>"> 
    <p id="p1">Name: <?php echo $row['Name']?>;</p>
                    <p>Genre: <?php echo $row['Genre']?></p>
                    <p>Release date: <?php echo $row['Release_date']?></p>
                    <p>Publisher: <?php echo $row['Publisher']?>:</p>
                    <p>Platforms: <?php echo $row['Platforms']?></p>
                </div>
                <?php
        }?>
    <input  type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit"></form>
        <?php
}else{
        echo "No results!";
    }
    </div>
            </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I am supposed to create `action="inc/delete.php"` script which will allow me to delete multiple rows using checkbox and submit button. Can someone help me out with this please ? I honestly have no clue on how to complete this ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to first set form method to `POST'

So, modify

`<form action="inc/delete.php" method="GET">`

To:

`<form action="inc/delete.php" method="post">`

And in `inc/delete.php`,

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Check if form is submitted.
 if (! empty($_POST['checkbox'])){ // Check if Checkbox is checked.
  // Loop over the checkbox and get selected ids.
  foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox_id){
    echo $checkbox_id."<br/>";
    // Add your delete query here.
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['checkbox']))
        {
            foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $check)
            {
                // delete query
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**NOTE: You failed to close PHP at line no. 40. Please make sure your PHP tag is closed or not.**

Answer (score 0):

So the resolution is that you get at your `delete` script `array` of ids. You can parse that array and execute DELETE query for each `id`:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
{
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $val)
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM Library WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $val);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Like @Pupil mentioned, and was right, you have to change your form action method.

Answer (score -1):

**inc/delete.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
 if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])){
  // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
  foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $row_id){
    echo $row_id."</br>";
    // DELETE QUERY HERE
  }
 }
}
?>
```